# MYSQL - Rows to Columns using join statement

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have to get data from 2 tables using join.1st table Name is sliprecord

```
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| cid    | cname     |   date            | totalAmount |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| 8      |   Umer    |   2015-12-15      |   1000      |
| 9      |   Shakir  |   2015-12-20      |   2000      |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
```

Another table Name is expense

```
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| idExpense    | title       |   date            | amount     |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| 1            |   BreakFast |   2015-12-15      |   300      |
| 2            |   Lunch     |   2015-12-15      |   500      |
| 3            |   Dinner    |   2015-12-17      |   700      |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
```

I want to create balance sheet, If sliprecord Table don't have a date in expense Table then it should also give me sliprecord date and sliprecord totalAmount .
And If expense don't have a date in sliprecord Table then it should also give me expense title,expense date,and expense amount .

Desired Out put should be like this:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| title       | EXP_date    | amount | Slip_date | totalAmount
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| BreakFast   |  2015-12-15 |  300   |2015-12-15 |   1000        
| Lunch       |  2015-12-15 |  500   |           |      
| Dinner      |  2015-12-17 |  700   |
|             |             |        |2015-12-20 |   2000 
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.  MySQL?  or SQL Server?

Comment: There is no any refrence key then how it is possible to calculate total amount.

Comment: So what have you done to try to get this? Please start by adding a [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry I am using MYSQL and there is no reference key ,I think it should be done with date